# boost and btrfs-tools failed with Yocto build

Tags: boost, yocto, btrfs

I am trying to build a custom Linux image using the Poky 2.6(thud) with ROS meta layer(thud-draft) in it. The image is built for a x86-64 system . The contents of my `bblayers.conf` file are given below

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""
ROS_DISTRO = "melodic"
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta-ros/meta-ros-common \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta-ros/meta-ros1-melodic \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta-ros/meta-ros-backports-warrior \
  /home/kogrob/devel/poky/meta-ros/meta-ros1 \
  "
```

The build failed with the following errors

```
Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/kogrob/poky/build-toaster-2/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/btrfs-tools/4.17.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.26496)

Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/kogrob/poky/build-toaster-2/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/boost/1.68.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.27908)
```

The boost build when it is build seperately using `bitbake boost` but the btrfs-tools fails everytime. What is the need of btrfs-tools and Is it possible to remove btrfs-tools and build an image without it.

The log files can be found here:
[log.do_compile.26496](https://github.com/ipa-rar/log.do_compile/blob/master/log.do_compile.26496)
[log.do_compile.27908](https://github.com/ipa-rar/log.do_compile/blob/master/log.do_compile.27908)

Comment: Please post the error messages as well they will be inside log.do_compile files

Comment: @Khem updated with the log.do_compile files

Comment: For the btrfs compilation it seems that you are missing the `setuptools` `pip install setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

On my Unbuntu host (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS x86_64), try the command:
`pip install setuptools`

but it doens't work, because the do_compile() use yocto generated python binary, not the one Ubuntu builtin, something like this:

```
build/tmp/work/aarch64-sdrv-linux/btrfs-tools/4.17.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3
```

.

Comment: The root cause is about the python mutli-versions in the yocto environment, yocto thud use **python3.5**, but meta-ros-backports-warrior override with **python3.7**